# How to get a inverse hexadecimal string from a hexadecimal string in shell

Tags: shell, hex, inverse

I do a practice to hexadecimal string inverse as followings

```
#!/bin/bash
HEX_STR="0001020355AA55AA"

## get ${INVERSE_HEX_STR}
## idea 1: echo ${HEX_STR} | xxd -r -p > ${BIN_FILE}, how to inverse ${BIN_FILE} ?


echo "inverse ${HEX_STR} is ${INVERSE_HEX_STR}"
```

How to get the inverse value saved to ${INVERSE_HEX_STR}

so the the output is :

```
inverse 0001020355AA55AA is FFFEFDFCAA55AA55
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr`:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
HEX_STR="0001020355AA55AA"

INVERSE_HEX_STR=`echo -n ${HEX_STR}|tr '0123456789ABCDEF' 'FEDCBA9876543210'`

echo "inverse ${HEX_STR} is ${INVERSE_HEX_STR}"
```

Comment: I noticed that too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash builtin xor `^` operator inside an arithmetic context and defining a function:

```
f() { 
   hex=$((0x$1))
   printf "inverse %X is %X\n" $hex $((hex ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
}
```

you can then use it like this:

```
f 0001020355AA55AA
inverse 1020355AA55AA is FFFEFDFCAA55AA55
```

Comment: you have a fixed length compliment. `f 0` returns `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, which doesn't seem quite right. How about `f ()
{
    HEX_STR="$1";
    len=${#HEX_STR};
    hex=$((0x$1));
    comp="0x$( while ((len--)); do printf "F"; done )";
    printf "inverse $HEX_STR is %X\n" $(( 0x$HEX_STR ^ comp ))
}` ?

Comment: I like that it's all-internal bash, though.

Comment: It can get correct compliment dependent on HEX_STR
but it is strange that output is always 16-character string



inverse 0001020355aa55aa0123456789abcdef is FEDCBA9876543210